# Why is ajax working on one server and not the next?

Tags: jquery, ajax, https

I have some script that works on my dev server but not on my staging server:

```
    add_action('wp_head','get_gz_info',30);
    function get_gz_info(){
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                var modal = {action:'modal_action'};
                var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
            $.post(ajaxurl,modal,function(data){
                $('body').append(data);
            });
        });
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

the php is roughly:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_modal_action', 'set_modal');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_modal_action', 'set_modal');
    function set_modal() {
...
}
```

Everything works fine on my dev side but the staging side the javascript is placed in the header (just like the dev) but it won't run the "ajax part". Could it be that the staging side requires a username/password to access it?

I've attempted it with and without the https and get the same results

----- EDIT -----

Note: I'm using ajax in the admin on the staging server it that works fine. It's only on the user side that I'm having an issue.

Comment: Are there are any errors in the console?

Comment: A few but nothing that relates the issue and that isn't seen on the dev server. Such as a font file warning and some issue chrome is having with a couple extensions.

Comment: if I print to the console or echo everything runs fine. Anything inside the $.post isn't run.

Comment: Have you verified that ajaxurl is being set correctly on the live server?  It's better to do it with a wp_localize_script() call.  Hate to link my own answer, but see step 2: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96795/using-jquery-to-delete-data-stored-in-wp-options/

Comment: According to the inspect this is being set as the ajaxurl, "http://...my site url.../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"

Comment: Ok, can you just change your php function to just echo 'baz' or something and then alert it in your callback?  Does that work?

Comment: Regarding your step 2. I have the js being placed in the head inside the php file of the plugin. The confusing issue is this works perfectly on one server but not the other.

Comment: No, anything inside the $.post call isn't doing anything. even if I alert or print to the console "test" and not the data from the callback.

Comment: I'm using ajax in the admin on the staging server it that works fine. It's only on the user side that I'm having an issue.

Comment: One thing I learned early was that best practices exist for a reason.  Go ahead and get your javascript included properly the WordPress way and then edit your code if it's still not working with the complete example.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: I've switched it to using your suggestion in your answer. The same issue occurs. Works on my dev server, not my staging server.

Comment: it seems like the ajaxurl isn't seeing the functions in the php that are connected to the action.

Comment: It's odd that it works on the admin side on the same server...

Comment: Just did a check to see if it even sees the admin-ajax.php file and it doesn't.

Comment: Check server permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The person who setup the staging server placed and .htaccess in the admin side that prevented the site from accessing files in the wp-admin area.